# TypeScript, define interface types in useGet custom hook

Tags: javascript, typescript

Coding this custom hook useGet, i would like to define the IStatus interface. For example loading status is clearly boolean, error: I tryed with Error or AxiosError types but i have an alert in VSCode (Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Error | null'). data: an empty Array ?. Thanks in advance.

> useGet.ts (custom hook)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useGet = (url: string) => {
  interface IStatus {
    loading: boolean;
    error: null | any;
    data: null | []
  }

  const [status, setStatus] = useState<IStatus>({
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    data: null
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios(url);    
      setStatus({
        loading: false,
        error: null,
        data: res.data
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setStatus({
        loading: false,
        error: error,
        data: null
      });
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return [status.data, status.loading, status.error]
}
```

> Component.tsx (consuming custom hook)

```js
import { useGet } from '../hooks/useGet';

const UseGetComponent = () => {
  interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
  }

  interface IPost {
    id: number;
    userId: number;
    title: string;
  }

  const [dataUsers, loadingUsers, errorUsers] = useGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const [dataPosts, loadingPosts, errorPosts] = useGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Custom hooks</h1>
      {loadingUsers && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {errorUsers && <div>Error: {errorUsers.message}</div>}
      {dataUsers && (
        <div >
          <ul>
            {dataUsers.map((user: IUser) => (
              <li key={user.id}>
              {user.name} - {user.email}
              {loadingPosts && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {errorPosts && <div>Error: {errorPosts.message}</div>}
              {dataPosts && (
                <ul>
                  {dataPosts
                    .filter((post: IPost) => post.userId === user.id)
                    .map((post: IPost) => (
                      <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
              )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default UseGetComponent
```

Comment: There are some issue here: 
- `getData` function body should be wrapped inside the useEffect to avoid the change of reference during rerender or wrapped inside a `useCallback`;
- I'm pretty sure this design is not enough flexible for you: in this way you are limiting the response to [] or null but you can improve that aspect and fix your issue.

You could pass a type argument to `useGet` in this way: `useGet<T>` and use this dynamic type to your interface and to axios response (you can type using AxiosResponse, I suggest checking the doc. This is important to not have the unknown type).

Comment: @Danielo To avoid some issue during rerender maybe i can use AbortController in async http request. Thanks for your sugerence of dynamic typing.